# How to import time with date

Tags: import, timestamp

Importing the date works correctly, but the time shown is always 12:00 am even though the import field is, for example  02/07/2018 11:31 am. I tried various formats like the previously mentioned 02/07/2018 11:31 am  or 03/04/2018 14:22.

How can I import the time and the date into a CiviCRM date field. I am importing the dates into a custom date field.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this is currently possible. The time part will we stripped in `CRM_Utils_Date::convertToDefaultDate()` called here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Contact/Import/Parser/Contact.php#L1909

You could have an extension read an imported text field with a date string and set the proper datetime value for the custom field via the hook `hook_civicrm_custom` in an extension. But adding the functionality to core would most likely make more sense.

Comment: is this still the case?

Comment: Yes, I'm not aware of anyone attempting to make changes yet.